# What is standard/considered best practice for the media used for different documentation?

Tags: documentation, engineering, industry-standard

I have just started my first position as a software engineer after finishing my degree, and, as warned, software is much different in industry than in academia. The startup that hired me does not have such robust documentation due to the pace of the work, and that is a piece that I would like to take on, and I want to do it right.

The first thing I noticed when thinking is that there are various types of documentation which would be useful for our company. To name a few:

- Documentation for external users on how to use the software
- Documentation for internal users (i.e. superadmins),
- Documentation for explaining code
- Documentation for developer setup
- Documentation for developer workflow (i.e. what are our DevOps practices, what processes should you follow when making a change to the codebase, etc.)
- Documentation for system architecture

My question: **what is standard/considered a best practice for the medium used to present these different types of documentation? Is there a standard or best practice?** I can imagine that the medium for the user docs (probably hosted on the website, company.io/docs) will not be the same as for code explanation, which will not be the same as for the developer setup.

On GitHub, for example, I have noticed that repos' READMEs are used pretty diversely. Some use it to explain to developers how to set up the repo locally, some use it to explain code, and some use it to explain features. Any answer or direction to external sources is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Software is _much_ too broad a field for there to be any kind of "one size fits all" recommendation.

Comment: jeeze these get closed fast! I think your question has a simple answer for each type of documentation. user - in the app itself, dev setup - read.me in git or similar,workflow/arch/project plans company intranet. I would advise you to avoid the documentation task as a newbie though. add a feature

Comment: @Ewan thanks, this is the answer I was looking for :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best practice for documentation is the newbie is the expert on how readable it is.

You're new. You're looking at the code and the documentation with the best critical eye. You can see what's been explained well and what hasn't.

The rest of the team doesn't have that. They have [The Curse of Knowledge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_knowledge). Which is a fancy way of saying they already know what they meant when they documented. So that's what they think of any time they read it. They don't think about what it actually says.

So the newbie is the ultimate athority on where the documentation falls short. The newbie should be updating it and getting feedback to ensure it remains correct.

If you find types of documentation to be completely missing then your problem is as you create it you're going to learn and get the curse. So seek out other newbies to review what you create. Find out what is actually useful vs what is just time wasting.

Documenting well is highly colaborative. Don't just make up whatever and pat yourself on the back. Get eyes on it and be sure you're helping.

Yes READMEs get used for a multitude of things. I've found freaking licence agreements in there. I could cite ISO standards at you but the most important thing is to put your stuff where it will be found by the people who need it.

> documentation for external users on how to use the software

Make the software as self-explanatory as possible. Beyond that, help for off-line users, wikis and web forums for online users.

> documentation for internal users (i.e. superadmins)

User wiki.

> documentation for explaining code,

Good names. A good name is better and preferable to any comment.

Comments that focus on why the code does what it does. Not how. Comments that show intent. Coders should explain what they were thinking. Not Java.

> documentation for developer setup, documentation for developer workflow (i.e. what are our DevOps practices, what processes should you follow when making a change to the codebase, etc.)., documentation for system architecture.

Dev wiki.

Comment: Spot on! I tend to term this "beginner's eyes", claiming that I'm a beginner only once, so my 2nd editing pass over your prose or comments won't be as valuable as the 1st one. Also, we routinely assume that "code which hasn't run is buggy", and during initial run of a unit test we step away from the blast zone. Similarly, "a ReadMe which hasn't been followed is buggy", so it's always an action item for a new hire reading a new document to take notes on what went wrong, and **update** the ReadMe to incorporate what we've learned.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer! I was, however, specifically asking about the location of the documentation, not its readability.

Comment: @Lavie I know. However, we discorage questions here that require entire books to answer. I was trying to pick out the answerable parts of your question. If you want I can delete this answer, but without more focus your question may get closed.

Comment: @Lavie that's the best I can do if you don't edit so I can vote to reopen. Looks like Ewan would like a chance to answer.

Comment: @candied_orange no problem, could you advise me on how to make it more focused? I could ask, for example, what a common practice is instead of a best practice? But that seems a little too opinion-based.

Comment: @Lavie Your "To name a few" list could use some highlighting. Make it a [bulleted or numbered list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/366240/the-styling-for-lists-numbered-and-bulleted-got-switched-to-none). It also might help to change "location" to "media". You're not asking which file drawer to poke the on boarding document in.